# VBA - delete cells that are not in an array (and for loop over arrays)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have two sheets of data. Sheet "mapping" contains names and next to names there are Pcodes (each name has different quantity of Pcodes). There is  a header in the first row, names in F2, F3 and F4, and Pcodes in G2, H2, I2, G3, G4, H4. The other sheet called "YTD" has only one column with Pcodes (Column "A" with a header).

The task is to copy the whole workbook as many time as the quantity of names (and rename the workbooks as names). And in the workbooks delete those Pcodes in sheets "YTD"  which are not belong to the name.

When I run the code only for for instance Ben, so e=2, the code works, however if I want to use the for loop to conduct the process through all three names ("For e=1 to num_names), it cannot recognize Pcodes well, and delete or does not delete cells correctly.

```
Sub Main_several_intofiles_new()
Dim e As Integer
Dim h As Integer
Dim u As Integer
Dim Pcodes() As String
Dim Names() As String
Dim xPath As String
Dim k As Long, j As Integer 'Big integers
Dim isThere As Boolean 'True or False

xPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

    ''Names
    Sheets("mapping").Activate

    lrow = Worksheets("mapping").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

    num_names = lrow - 1

    ReDim Names(1 To num_names) As String

    For h = 1 To num_names
        Names(h) = Cells(1 + h, 6)
    Next h
    ''


''For cycle through the names
For e = 1 To num_names
'e = 2

    ''New file
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        xPath & Names(e) & ".xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=Fals
    ''


    ''Pcodes
    Sheets("mapping").Activate

    lcolumn = Worksheets("mapping").Cells(1 + e, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    num_pcodes = lcolumn - 6


    
    ReDim Pcodes(1 To num_pcodes) As String

    For u = 1 To num_pcodes
        Pcodes(u) = Cells(e + 1, 6 + u).Value
    Next u
    ''
    
    

    ''Delete row, if cell in column "A"
    Sheets("YTD").Activate

    For k = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

           For j = LBound(Pcodes) To UBound(Pcodes)
            If StrComp(Range("A" & k), Pcodes(j), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                isThere = True
            End If
        Next j
        If Not isThere Then
            Range("A" & k).Delete
        End If
        isThere = False
    Next k
    ''
    
Next e

MsgBox (":)")

End Sub
```

Comment: You said that it works when e = 2, but not for any other value?  Sounds like e is causing problems.  What do you mean by "it cannot recognize Pcodes well, and delete or does not delete cells correctly"?  Are you sure you're referencing the right range on the sheet in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I tried the code when e=1, e=2 and e=3 and all these three cases work well (I have 3 names). So I think there is no problem with the expressions which contain e. I also defined e as integer. The sentence which you hilighted means that the code has to delete those Pcodes which do not belong to the person, and does not delete those which belong to the person. If you have any thoughts on this problem feel free to comment. Thx

Comment: Your problems *might* because you're sometimes referring to the ranges in the original workbook, and you're sometimes referring to the ranges in the new workbooks.  One thing to make your life easier is to explicitly reference which workbook you're using.  Step through your code line by line to make sure you're referencing the right sheet.  Also, consider testing with a smaller, simpler case to make sure you understand how it's all working.